# Is it possible to define 'step' size when iterating over a C++ container?

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

I know of the simple way to iterate, for instance, over every character of a string as so:

```cpp
std::string some_string("Hello World");
for(auto character : some_string)
    std::cout << character << std::endl;
```

But is there a way to use this construction to also tell it to take steps, or take specific lengths of the container in this way? Or would I have to use the classic `int i = 0; i < some_string.length(); i+=2` construction for iterating over the string indices and storing parts of it with `string.substr()`? For instance if I wanted to store every 2 characters of a string as a substring.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You need a for loop using iterators, or an indexed loop.

Comment: You could write your own iterators for that.

Comment: Unfortunate. I was hopeful with how advanced C++ got, especially in C++20.

Comment: @tkausl Well, that's possible, but probably not worth the efforts.

Comment: Simple readable code > some hacky trick that looks cool.

Comment: @JackAvante -- The boost library has [stride iterators](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/boost/compute/iterator/strided_iterator.hpp).  Maybe in C++ 23 or beyond, they can be adopted by the standards committee.

Comment: `bool tiktok = false; for (auto c : s) { tiktok = !tiktok; if (tiktok) continue; cout << c << "\n"; }`

Comment: `views::stride(n)` from [ranges-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) can do this (`for (auto character : some_string | views::stride(2))`). Also [`boost::adaptors::strided(n)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html) with similar syntax

Comment: @Artyer You should post `views::stride()` as an answer to both, I would say, since `range-v3` is the basis of Standard Ranges and therefore there's a good change the stdlib will get `stride()` in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This range based for loop (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)):

```
for ( init-statement(optional)range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

is equivalent to:

```
{

    init-statement
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement

    }

}
```

(see link for what `begin_expr` and `end_expr` are and more details)

There is no (easy) way to make it increment more than one. The advantage of the range based for loop is that you need not care about indices or iterators. If you want to do something with indices, then using the range based loop is not an advantage.